# HTML file not generated on my computer after publishing the map with qgis2web

Tags: qgis, export, html, qgis2web

I have exported a map using qgis2web plug-in in QGIS 3.16.12, but it does not generate the HTML file on my computer, although the option "Export to a folder" is active.

How can I fix this?

[image: folders created]

Comment: and what is inside the folder the plugin generates? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: hi, sure, see above. all the folders created are empty, as well.

Comment: Did you to select another folder? What does the preview of the map in the plugin show?

Comment: maybe it's a permission problem in the folder, try to select the Desktop folder and export again. usually if an export fails you also get an error message in qgis, do you get something?